# IProgressDialog with a custom dialog or information about how the animation is performed

Tags: winapi, windows-vista

There are basically two questions here, an answer to either is fine.

1) Is there a way to add items into an IProgressDialog?  Such as drawing more text (than the few lines provided) or an image or adding a button?  Is there a class that overrides this that provides extra functionality?  (Since I'm not doing a file operation, the IFileOperation interface doesn't work for me.  But is there something similar?).

or

2) How does the animation at the top of IProgressDialog work?  Is there a way to perform just that animation without using this interface?  I know on pre-vista machines, it was just an AVI file, but how is it done now?  (Short of just drawing 100 images with a timer).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no system support for extending the standard progress dialog. However you could find the HWND of the dialog, and then add your own controls.

Perhaps it's better if you create your own [animation control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).